# adding 2 lists to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
[(12,3,1),(12,3,5)]
```

and two other lists

```
 [4,2]
```

and

```
['A','B']
```

i want to add these to the first list to make

```
[(12,3,4,'A',1),(12,3,2,'B',5)
```

They have to be in this position as i plan to remove the ones with 1 as the last value in the tuple

Comment: Have you attempted this? It appears you are splitting your problem into parts and posting each bit until it's solved. I haven't seen code from you attempting it yet.

Comment: Also, you will have to explain why the lists are added where they are. Is the position arbitrary?

Comment: are there any reasons for keeping the positions other than removing the one's?

Comment: It might be best if you describe what you are trying to program, instead of figuring out of how to make your solution work.

Comment: I have 2 list of integers, 1 list of characters and a list of tuples. I need to join them together and then remove some of them depending on if they have a 1 at the end of the tuple

Comment: you can also *first* remove the ones with `1` at the end and then add it to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def submerge(d, e, f):
    for g in d[:-1]:
        yield g
    yield e
    yield f
    yield d[-1] # if you want to remove the last element just remove this line

def merge(a, b, c):
    for d, e, f in zip(a, b, c):
        yield tuple(submerge(d, e, f))

a = [(12,3,1),(12,3,5)]
b = [4,2]
c = ['A','B'] 

print list(merge(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 3):

Look, here's some magic:

```
ts = [(12, 3, 1), (12, 3, 5)]
l1 = [4, 2]
l2 = ['A', 'B'] 
[t[:-1] + to_insert + t[-1:] for t, to_insert in zip(ts, zip(l1, l2))]
>> [(12, 3, 4, 'A', 1), (12, 3, 2, 'B', 5)]
```